# Can kube state metrics scrape pod annotations?

Tags: prometheus, kube-state-metrics

have a question, can KSM get pod annotations? I need it for dynamic alert emailing. So i can't use email in pod label which is scraped by KSM. I found in github that it probably can scrape pod annotation, but i don't have this metric in my KSM, so mb it included in some new version? Maybe smb know more about it?

appreciate for answering. Have a good day ^^